# TSQL Text Field Encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption, password-encryption

very new to TSQL encryption.. could someone please tell me what data type would be best to use to store encrypted text data (e.g. Encrypted storage of secret passwords, password hints, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are going to use [ENCRYPTBYKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql) to encrypt your data, you can see that its return value is `VARBINARY`:

> varbinary with a maximum size of 8,000 bytes.
>
> Returns NULL if the key
>   is not open, if the key does not exist, or if the key is a deprecated
>   RC4 key and the database is not in compatibility level 110 or higher.

So, it is clear that you need to use `VARBINARY` to store the encrypted values.  The length of the `VARBINARY` column will vary based on the length of the data you are encrypting and the type of algorithm being used.

Some people generate the maximum possible value that can be encrypted to check the maximum possible encryption value length. For example, using the `ALGORITHM = AES_256` and encrypting `NVARCHAR(128)` field:

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY StackOverflow WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pass123_@';
GO

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY StackOverflow
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pass123_@'
go

DECLARE @MaximumColumnValue NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @EncrpytionValue VARBINARY(8000);

SET @MaximumColumnValue = replicate (N'A', 128)
PRINT DATALENGTH(@MaximumColumnValue);

SET @EncrpytionValue = EncryptByKey( key_guid('StackOverflow'), @MaximumColumnValue )
PRINT DATALENGTH(@EncrpytionValue);

DROP SYMMETRIC KEY StackOverflow;
GO
```